# DateTimePicker does not displaying data even after I clicked a date to display

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker control on my WinForm with its CheckBox property enabled.
during the runtime when I want to select a date it does not show it in datetimepicker textbox, I know my code is correct cause the same code is working on the other form I have, but not in this one!

below is a snapshot of my code, any help is would be appreciated:

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
DateTimePicker1.Enabled = True
DateTimerPicker1.Checked = False
If DateTimePicker1.Checked = False Then
        DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "
        DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    Else
        DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Reza Aghaie check I want like this]

Comment: You told it to don't show a date using `DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "`

Comment: No that is clear that it will not show a date if it is DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " " | it is not showing the date even when I check the checkbox or select a date from datetimepicker

Comment: You set `DateTimerPicker1.Checked = False` and so this code will execute DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "
        DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom

Comment: @RezaAghaei that's what I want from above code, but it should change when I select a date! if you want I can share snap of my form for better understanding?

Comment: you can use those codes in ValueChanged event

Comment: no I am sure that there is nothing wrong in above code, I think there is some other thing in my current form that is not allowing me to perform my preferred action otherwise it would have worked same like it worked in the previous form that I have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle change of that check box, you can use `ValueChanged` event:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    If Me.DateTimePicker1.Checked=True Then
       Me.DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
    Else
       Me.DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
       Me.DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "
     End If
End Sub
```

In your code, you told it to don't show a date using `DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "`.

See the comments that I added to your code below:

```
DateTimerPicker1.Checked = False '<==== You set Checked to false
If DateTimePicker1.Checked = False Then  '<==== You told if not checked (it's not checked)
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " "  '<==== Show space
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
....
```

Comment: Reza look I shared a picture of my previous form which I used the same code as above for it and it is working fine

Comment: Thank you everything was fine, I was just missing to add the same code to DateTimePicker_ValueChanged event as well :p but now that you posted I just remembered what I had done before and was not doing it this time :)